# MYSQL LIMIT LEVENSHTEIN

Tags: php, mysql, similarity

So here is my query which works, but how can I limit this where the distance value is between 0 and 4?

> SELECT title, LEVENSHTEIN(title, 'A MATCHING ') AS distance FROM
>   `jb_jobs` WHERE description LIKE "%lorem%" ORDER BY distance DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT title, LEVENSHTEIN(title, 'A MATCHING ') AS distance
FROM jb_jobs
WHERE description LIKE '%lorem%'
HAVING distance <= 4
ORDER BY distance DESC;
```

The use of `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` in this fashion is a MySQL extension.  In other databases, you would typically use a subquery or CTE.  However, subqueries add additional overhead (because MySQL materializes them) and MySQL does not support CTEs.

Comment: Oh so you can use HAVING on aliases I didn't know that, thank you!

Comment: but if I want to use LEVENSHTEIN on two fields, let's say I want to add to the description as well.. and I will create an alias as distance_two how can I do it for both fields? can you update your answer with an example? I can accept it in a few minutes

Comment: @Uffo . . . Yes.  Some databases support `HAVING` on aliases (not all).  MySQL goes a step further by not requiring the `GROUP BY `.

Comment: @Uffo . . . How the alias is defined in the `SELECT` doesn't matter.  You can even have expressions in the `HAVING` that use aliases.

Comment: But this doesn't work with 2 fields SELECT title, LEVENSHTEIN(title, 'FULL STACK GURU only') AS distance FROM jb_jobs WHERE LEVENSHTEIN(description, 'lorem') AS distance_two HAVING distance <= 4 OR distance_two <=4 ORDER BY distance DESC

Comment: @Uffo . . . If you have another question, ask it as *another* question, not in a comment.